# Break data link of map charts in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-powerpoint, refresh

I have an Excel file with map charts to monitor wildfires from a national database. I create maps of e.g. number of fires per administrative region, for different years. I insert the map for say 2019 in PowerPoint for a presentation, and I go to file>info>Edit-links-to-files>break-link, so that the map doesn't change when i chose 2020 in the original excel file.

That works for other types of charts, but the map-charts keep refreshing, even after breaking the link. I've also tried a paste special as a "Microsoft Office Graphic Object", and breaking the link, but no sucess. I could paste as a picture of course, but I need other people in my organization to be able to change e.g. color scale, labels, etc.

I didn't find any reference to that issue, someone is experiencing the same ? Any solution ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I download a workbook with several map chart examples from "[Create a Map chart in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-map-chart-in-excel-f2cfed55-d622-42cd-8ec9-ec8a358b593b)", I also insert map charts as "Microsoft Office Graphic Object" from Paste Special, but if I break the links, the charts in prenseation could not be updated. Even I click Update Now button, there would be a pormpt, that [the linked file isn't avaliable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v54D.png). I suggest you test in a new presnseation.

Answer (score 0):

Just do  (in power point) :

```
After paste > (bottom right) Choose : Picture
```

That should do. Please share if it works/not.